# What's the meaning of FindVertexCut?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.1**

---

Is there a conflict in these two places in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexConnectivity.en.html)?

In the **Basic Examples**:

[image: basic example]

Then the **Properties & Relations**

[image: properties and relations]

But actually:

[image: my attempt]

Comment: Also (smaller graph) `VertexConnectivity[Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}], 1, 2]` vs `FindVertexCut[Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}], 1, 2]`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Do you think this two place are in conflict as a general rule?

Comment: I believe the second one is erroneous

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Yeah.I also think so.

Comment: I also suspect that `FindVertexCut` has a bug.