# Find ALL minimum vertex cuts in a directed graph

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and persisting through 12.1**

---

[image]

Suppose I have this graph

```
edges = {TX -> R1, R1 -> R3, R3 -> R5, R5 -> RX, TX -> R2, R2 -> R4, 
   R4 -> R6, R6 -> RX, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R3 -> R4, R4 -> R5, 
   R5 -> R6, TX -> R7, TX -> R8, R7 -> R9, R9 -> R6, R9 -> RX, 
   R8 -> R6};
```

When I use `FindVertexCut[edges, TX, RX]` it returns node `{R5, R6}`. To disconnect this graph I should be getting `{R5,R6,R7}` and `{R5,R6,R9}`. Any advice? Basically, how can I find the ALL minimum cut sets and minimum path sets where a set may contain 1 element, 2 elements, 3 elements, ..., n elements?

Comment: In the version you use does `FindVertexCut` work on the `edges` list directly?  In v10.1 I need to use `Graph`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Since v10.4 (I think) almost all graph related functions can take a rule list.

Comment: Attempting to work through this I wonder if the problem is underspecified, or if your example is poor.  The two *n=3* examples you give are supersets of `{R5, R6}`.  Would not this family of cuts be R5, R6, and one of *any* of the other nodes beside TX and RX?  Is that really what you want?

Comment: just an observation, the same issue persists if we make this an *undirected* graph. `FindVertexCut[g, TX, RX]->{R5, R6}` *however* `FindVertexCut[g, RX, TX]`  correctly gives `{R5, R6, R9}`.   Clearly there is a bug here.

Answer (score 2):

This question relate with my [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105043/21532).The `VertexConnectivity[edges,TX,RX]` give a right answer,but `FindVertexCut[edges, TX, RX]` will not..

```
edges = {TX -> R1, R1 -> R3, R3 -> R5, R5 -> RX, TX -> R2, R2 -> R4, 
   R4 -> R6, R6 -> RX, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R3 -> R4, R4 -> R5, 
   R5 -> R6, TX -> R7, TX -> R8, R7 -> R9, R9 -> R6, R9 -> RX, 
   R8 -> R6};
```

---

## Method one(violence but reliable)

This is a workaroud can find all vertex cut as its definition.Of course,this method based on `Subsets`,which mean it is very **low efficiency**.I hope it be refined by other user.

Find all vertex set except that start and end vertex

```
vertexSets = Rest[Subsets[Complement[VertexList[edges], {TX, RX}]]]
```

Find the vertex connectivity

```
vertexConn = Catch[Do[If[! WeaklyConnectedGraphQ[VertexDelete[Graph[edges], i]], 
    Throw[Length[i]]], {i, vertexSets}]]
```

> 3

Then you can select those vertex cut

```
Select[GroupBy[vertexSets, Length][vertexConn], 
   !WeaklyConnectedGraphQ[VertexDelete[Graph[edges], #]] &]
```

> {{R5,R6,R7},{R5,R6,R9}}

---

## Method two(based on `VertexConnectivity`)

Of course,if you trust that function `VertexConnectivity` totally,there is a **higher efficiency** and more **concise** method

```
Select[Subsets[Complement[
   VertexList[edges], {TX, RX}], {VertexConnectivity[edges, TX, 
    RX]}], ! WeaklyConnectedGraphQ[VertexDelete[edges, #]] &]
```

> {{R5, R6, R7}, {R5, R6, R9}}

Answer (score 1):

here is an approach that recursively drops vertices along the shortest path:

```
edges = {TX -> R1, R1 -> R3, R3 -> R5, R5 -> RX, TX -> R2, R2 -> R4, 
   R4 -> R6,
   R6 -> RX, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R3 -> R4, R4 -> R5, R5 -> R6,
   TX -> R7, TX -> R8, R7 -> R9, R9 -> R6, R9 -> RX, R8 -> R6} ;
g = Graph[edges];
droppv[{g_Graph /; WeaklyConnectedGraphQ[g], dl_List}, a_, b_] :=
 droppv[{VertexDelete[g, #], Append[dl, #]}, a, b] & /@ 
  FindShortestPath[g, a, b][[2 ;; -2]]
SortBy[Sort /@ 
   Cases[droppv[{g, {}}, TX, RX] , 
    droppv[{ g_Graph , dl_}, _, _] :> dl , Infinity] // Union, Length]
```

this gives all unique sets of vertices to disconnect the graph:

> {{R5, R6, R7}, {R5, R6, R9}, {R1, R2, R6, R7}, {R1, R2, R6, R9}, {R1, 
>     R2, R7, R8}, {R1, R2, R8, R9}, ... (54 sets)

pick the minimum length sets:

```
Select[%, Length[#] == Length[%[[1]]] &]
```

> > {{R5, R6, R7}, {R5, R6, R9}}

Comment: **ALL minimum** flash my eyes, or maybe I have missed something.:)

Comment: ok, so pick the first two.. @yode

Comment: Or `MinimalBy[#, Length] &`..