# How to Breakout Edge Betweenness Centrality

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider the following:

```
Clear[edges, graph]
edges = {TX -> R1, R1 -> R3, R3 -> R5, R5 -> RX, TX -> R2, R2 -> R4, 
   R4 -> R6, R6 -> RX, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R3 -> R4, R4 -> R5, 
   R5 -> R6, TX -> R7, TX -> R8, R7 -> R9, R9 -> R6, R9 -> RX, 
   R8 -> R6};
graph = Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
SortBy[{EdgeList[edges], 
   EdgeBetweennessCentrality[edges]}\[Transpose], N@*Last]
```

The output is

[image]

[image]

Can the results listed above for each vertex pair be broken out to include the {EdgeBetweennessCentrality, x, y}, where x is the total number of shortest paths that contain **that** specific vertex pair and y is the total number of shortest paths in the entire network? For example, a list {{R1->R2, 1.83333, x, y},...,{R3->R5, 6.33333, x, y}} would be produced with the x and y values specific to R1->R2, ..., R3->R5 and so forth.

Finally, the above is a directed graph. Can a similar analysis be done for an undirected graph?

ALL VERTEX PAIRS

```
Normal@AdjacencyMatrix@graph;
allVertexPairs = Permutations[VertexList@graph, {2}]
Length[%]
shortestPaths = FindShortestPath[graph, All, All] @@@ allVertexPairs
Length[%]
NonNullshortestPaths = Select[shortestPaths, UnsameQ[#, {}] &]
Length[%]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _total number of shortest paths in the entire network_? Do you mean all 24 possible paths from TX to RX (``FindPath[graph, TX, RX, All, All]``)? Or do you mean all possible shortest paths connecting any two vertices (``Catenate@Catenate@Table[FindPath[graph, i, j, {GraphDistance[graph, i, j]}, All], {i, VertexList[graph]}, {j, VertexList[graph]}] /. {} -> Nothing``) – there's 50 of them.

Comment: I'm referring to All Vertex Pairs, for example, this is the code that would generate All Vertex Pairs:

Comment: I just added code for All Vertex Pairs (see above)

Comment: Looking for all possible shortest paths that contain any two vertices; my code above found 38 of them, when the nulls {} are eliminated from the list.

Comment: Your Catenate code looks more complete with finding the 50 versus my code finding 38.

Comment: ``FindShortestPath`` returns _one_ shortest path, but there can be more of them with the same length. Compare ``FindShortestPath[graph, All, All][TX, R3]`` and ``FindPath[graph, TX, R3, All, All]``.

Comment: True, it will fine one shortest path. I like your Catenate code above; with that, how can I unpack the edge betweenness centrality in the manner described above? Thoughts?

Comment: I have posted an answer. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: That's an old old test network. It was already in [one of your first questions here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141584/12) :-) When I see this network, I now know who is asking without having to look. Now I am getting really curious about why this specific graph is interesting to you?

Comment: Hello Szabolcs: You are right. This DAG is one I often use to check various calculations in Mathematica. In this case, I basically am trying to verify by direct calculation the EdgeBetweennessCentrality generated by Mathematica. Has anyone done some of these checks? One reason I do this comes from my experience with Mathematica's FindMinimumCut. In older versions (prior to v12.3) it would sometimes be problemmatic; hence, I try to verify certain network algorithms Mathematica uses to generate outputs, to be sure I understand how it is being done.

Comment: *"I basically am trying to verify by direct calculation the EdgeBetweennessCentrality generated by Mathematica."* Yes, I have done this check. You can verify it with [IGEdgeBetweenness](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#betweenness) from my IGraph/M package. Note that for some reason EdgeBetweennessCentrality returns _twice_ the result I'd expect in _undirected_ graphs. Somehow it treats undirected graphs as directed with reciprocal edges. Try `EdgeBetweennessCentrality[Graph[{1 <-> 2}]]`. It gives 2 and not 1. Other than this I believe it's correct.

Comment: Code I used to verify vertex betweenness directly is here: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/1316#issuecomment-636313672  I have something for edge betweenness as well but I don't remember where I put it. I can look it up if you need it.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I believe 2 is correct according to the definition. $\sum_{ij} \sigma_{ij}^{(e)}/\sigma_{ij}= [i=1,j=2] + [i=2, j=1]=1/1+1/1=2$. Undirected edge can hold paths in both directions.

Comment: @Domen That depends on what definition you take. This is not the usual definition that people use. In undirected graphs, we look at paths between unordered pairs. In directed graphs, between ordered pairs. Mathematica's way of calculating this is definitely the outlier here. Also, it's inconsistent with how it calculates vertex betweenness, where it takes unordered pairs.  I consider this a bug, and I've reported it many years ago, but they didn't respond.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks for the clarification, I see it now! [Networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.edge_betweenness_centrality.html) returns 1 as well. (In the WRI's defense, they do, _implicitly_ state that the definition is different, because it says _"For graphs on one or more edges, edge betweenness centralities lie between $2$ and $2\left \lfloor{2n^2/4}\right \rfloor$ inclusive"_ :-))

Comment: I'm still trying the numerically verify how Mathematica calculates the values in the 2nd col from the left. Consider those column of values and then compare then them with the column of values in the 3rd col from the left. TX->R2 is 3.16667 (from Mathematica) but TX->R2 is on 5 shortest paths out of the 50 shortest paths across this little example network. R2->R3 is 2.66667 (Mathematica) but also occurs on 5 shortest paths out of 50 shortest paths across this network. Mathematica can produce different values (Col 2) that have the same values in Col 3 is my question.

Answer (score 4):

```
edges = {TX -> R1, R1 -> R3, R3 -> R5, R5 -> RX, TX -> R2, R2 -> R4, 
   R4 -> R6, R6 -> RX, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R3 -> R4, R4 -> R5, 
   R5 -> R6, TX -> R7, TX -> R8, R7 -> R9, R9 -> R6, R9 -> RX, 
   R8 -> R6};
graph = Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> Automatic];

allShortestPaths = 
  Flatten[Table[
     FindPath[graph, i, j, {GraphDistance[graph, i, j]}, All], {i, 
      VertexList[graph]}, {j, VertexList[graph]}] /. {} -> Nothing, 2];

SortBy[Transpose[{
    EdgeList[edges],
    EdgeBetweennessCentrality[edges],
    Length@Cases[allShortestPaths, {___, #[[1]], #[[2]], ___}] & /@ edges,
    ConstantArray[Length@allShortestPaths, Length@edges]
   }], #[[2]] &] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Domen: This looks very nice. I very much appreciate your help!! I would have expected you to use your Catenate code but I see that the 50 is correct; last two questions: 1. Any insights into how the EdgeBetweenness Centrality column (e.g., R3->R5 with 6.33333) derives from the last two columns on the right (R3->R5 with 10, 50) and 2. What are you thoughts about this if the graph was UNDIRECTED? Again, many thanks!

Comment: Ahh, I see it now, you are actually interested in the definition of edge betweenness centrality! Let me just quickly resolve your troubles (I may edit the answer later). Look at the [definition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeBetweennessCentrality.html#FunctionEssay): $EB(e) = \sum_i \sum_j (\sigma_{ij}^{(e)}/\sigma_{ij})$. Although $\sum_i \sum_j 1/\sigma_{ij}$ is indeed constant, you cannot factorise this expression into $(\sum_i \sum_j \sigma_{ij}^{(e)})/(\sum_i \sum_j \sigma_{ij})$, which is what you are suggesting in your comment. Example: $(1/3)+(2/4)\neq(1+2)/(3+4)$.

Comment: I really like the values you show in the last two right-hand columns ... the second one in from the right is really the "stress" the path segment (link) is experiencing and that is a very helpful metric - one I feel is a good measure of edge betweenness. How Wolfram calculates their EdgeBetweenness centrality looks like it involves a normalization (it seems it is doing a 1/((n-1)(n-2))) normalization w/this being a directed graph.